# maximum earning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How can I calculate the maximum money earned of m tickets of n ticket windows that the price of a ticket is equal to the reamaining number of tickets that window?

There are n ticket windows in the railway station. The with window has a(j) tickets available. The price of a ticket is equal to the number of tickets remaining in that window at that time. What is the maximum amount of money the railway station can earn from selling the first m tickets?

For example if we got 3 ticket windows, have tickets of 3, 3, 4, and we want to sell 5 tickets. Then:

```
n = 3, m = 5
A[3] = {3, 3, 4}
```

The maximum money earned is 4 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2 = 15

I saw this question online and my solution is to first push all tickets numbers to a maxHeap and run a for loop for m times. Every time we pop the top value of the maxHeap and add it to the total money earned and if the value is bigger than 1 we push (value - 1) to the maxHeap.

But this is somehow too time consuming any better solutions?

Comment: You don't need to remove tickets one by one. If you have a top window, you need to know how many tickets it has and how many tickets the next one has. Then you can remove the difference and calculate the total price in one operation. With a slight modification you can do the same if you have several windows with the same max number of tickets.

Comment: Forgive me but I'm actually having trouble deciphering the question being asked here.  What does a(j) represent (are we being given an array of tickets per window?).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, we need to make an observation:

- To get the maximum result, we need to get the top most `m` tickets.

Let `x` be the maximum number of tickets left in a window, so the money one window `i` contributes to the total earning is

```
(a(i) + a(i) - 1 + ... + x + 1) = a(i)*(a(i) + 1)/2 - x*(x + 1)/2
```

To find `x`, we can use binary search

```
int start = 0;
int end = maximum number of ticket in one window;
while(start <= end)
   int mid = (start + end)/2;
   for(each window)
      number of sell ticket += a(i) - mid;//if mid is larger than a(i), just add a zero
   if(number of sell ticket >= m)
      increase start;
   else
      decrease end;
```

So, time complexity is O(n log m) with n is number of window and m is maximum number of ticket in one window.

Comment: What is the initializer for end? what does maximum number of ticket in one window mean for the example cace?

Comment: @user3692521 for case `A[3] = {3, 3, 4}`, so `end = 4`, for case `A[3] = {3, 3, 10}` , so `end = 10`. It is the maximum element in array `A`.

Comment: but how does this compute the maximum money earned?

Comment: @user3692521 to get the maximum result, in your current approach, you remove ticket layer by layer right, first, we remove all ticket from a(i) = 4, then a(i) = 3, ... and finally, when it reach layer a(i) = x, you stop. So this approach will help you find `x` faster. Imagine using a knife to chop off the top of a cake, and the chop off part has area equal to k, while the cake is the combination of all windows.

Comment: but x for each window could be different

Comment: could you modify your answer to a function has signature of maximumMoney(vector<int> tickets, int m)

Comment: And we may not stop at the same layer for every window

Comment: @user3692521 correct, but the different will only be 1, so x or x + 1, this only need one more for loop to check, so it is not a big issue. Just need to handle the binary search more carefully to get what you want ( upper bound or lower bound - which mean x or x + 1, depending on your taste).

Comment: @user3692521 to be more clear, there is no reason one window has x and other one has x + 2 or more, as this will produce less profit. You can just take one from column x + 2 to produce x + 1 and x + 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you use max heap, it can be done in O(m*logn). Here is C++ code -

```
int main() {
        int *inputArray;
        int n;
        int m;
        cin >> n;
        cin >> m;
        inputArray = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> inputArray[i];
        }
        cout << maximize(inputArray, n, m) << "\n";

        return 0;
    }

int maximize(int *inputArray, int n, int m){

        vector<int> v(inputArray, inputArray + n);
        int sum = 0;

        // make max heap
        make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

        for (m = 4; m != 0; m--) {
            // get max value
            int max = v.front();

            // move max value to end and heapify
            pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            // pop it out
            v.pop_back();

            sum = sum + max;

            if (max - 1) {
                // insert m-1 into vector
                v.push_back(max - 1);
                // heapify the new vector
                push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        package package1;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RailwayStation{
    int numOfTickets, ticketsToSell;
    int[] ticketsPerBooth;

    public RailwayStation(int numOfTickets, int ticketsToSell, int[] ticketsPerBooth)
    {
        this.numOfTickets = numOfTickets;
        this.ticketsToSell = ticketsToSell;
        this.ticketsPerBooth = ticketsPerBooth;
    }

    public int findMaxRevenue()
    {
        int[] perBooth = this.ticketsPerBooth;
        Arrays.sort(perBooth);
        int i = perBooth.length-1;
        int revenue = 0;
        while(i>=0 && ticketsToSell!=0){

            int diff = 0;
            if(i==0){

                diff = 1;
            }else{
                diff = perBooth[i] - perBooth[i-1];
            }

            while(diff!=0 && ticketsToSell!=0){

                revenue = revenue + perBooth[i];
                perBooth[i]--;
                diff--;
                ticketsToSell--;

            }
            if(ticketsToSell!=0 && i==0){
                i = perBooth.length-1;
            }else{
                i--;
            }


        }
        return revenue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfBooths = sc.nextInt();
        int ticketsToSell = sc.nextInt();
        int perBooth[] = new int[numOfBooths];
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfBooths; i++)
        {
            perBooth[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        RailwayStation rt = new RailwayStation(numOfBooths, ticketsToSell, perBooth);
        System.out.println("Max Revenue = " + rt.findMaxRevenue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"""modified factorial that sums up till the index limit of the round"""

def modified_fact(limit, number):
    sum_fact = 0
    for i in range(number - limit + 1, number + 1):
        sum_fact += i
    return sum_fact

'''
I've calculated how many rounds I would have to do to decrement. And in the last iteration upto what index I would need 
to iterate.

'''

def maximum_earning_algorithm(n, windows):
    """

```
:param windows:
:param n:
:rtype: int
"""
money = 0
final_round_limit_index = n % len(windows)
rounds = n / (len(windows))
print final_round_limit_index, rounds
for i in range(len(windows)):
    if i < final_round_limit_index:
        money += modified_fact(rounds + 1, windows[i])
    else:
        money += modified_fact(rounds, windows[i])
return money
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    window = [5, 4, 3]
    print maximum_earning_algorithm(3, window)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1)**
As @n.m. pointed out the little optimization on the MaxHeap solution:

You don't need to remove tickets one by one. If you have a top window, you need to know how many tickets it has and how many tickets the next one has. Then you can remove the difference and calculate the total price in one operation.
With a slight modification, you can do the same if you have several windows with the same max number of tickets.

---

**Approach 2) using sorted array:**

Load the windows into an array. Sort the array. Go backwards through the array and as you do: store that number (current), add it to the aggregator, go to the next value. If it is the same (current), then add it to aggregator, subtract 1 from it, keep going. If it is different, go back to the end of the array and start again. Do that N times (the internal loop, not the external one).

---

**Approach 3) using count array (linear time complexity):**

1. Create an array with index as no. of tickets and values as no. of stalls having those many number of tickets. So {0->0, 1->1, 2->0, 3->2} means 1 stall have 1 ticket and 2 stalls have 3 tickets)
2. Start at the highest index of the array (count -1) and add that index to your aggregator (A) so A = 3, and then reduce that index (3) by 1 to 1, and increase the index below (=2) by 1 to 1.
   Array is {0,1,1,1} and A=3. Repeat. A=6, array is {0,1,2,0}. Last index is zero, so move your pointer to index 2.
   Repeat, so A=8, array = {0,2,1,0}. Repeat. A=10, array is {0,5,0,0}.
   Stop when you've done this t times (for number of tickets sold.)

*Here's the implementation of this approach:*

```
int[] stalls = new int[] { 3,1,3 }; // 2 stalls have 3 tickets each and 1 stall have 1 ticket
        int t = 4;

        Arrays.sort(stalls);

        int tickets = stalls[stalls.length - 1];
        int[] dp = new int[tickets + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < stalls.length; i++) {
            dp[stalls[i]]++;
        }

        int total = 0;
        int i = dp.length - 1;

        while (t > 0) {
            if (dp[i] > 0) {
                total += i;
                t--;
                dp[i]--;
                dp[i - 1]++;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);
```